# Why can I not use any PIP commands? Mac & Conda

Tags: python, macos, pip, anaconda

## Pip Commands suddenly not working...

I have used Python for various projects in the past. I suspected that it might be a path issue, but my `pwd` outputs `Users/MyUserName/`.

#### When I enter even a basic PIP command such as `pip --version` in the console, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MyUserName/anaconda3/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: If cannot sort it out, recommend using: colab.research.google.com

Comment: It looks like you're running `pip` in a Python script / notebook, instead of in the terminal. Try going to the terminal and running `pip install -U pip`. What does it do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+TypeError%3A+%27module%27+object+is+not+callable

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate all the responses! Turns out it had to do with me having Python both within and without the Conda "shell". Using `conda` in place of `pip` seems to work!